# Using matplotlib with latex mode with non-default fonts

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, latex

I am using Windows 10 with Anaconda and Spyder 4. When using `matplotlib`, I would like to use the font `Proxima Nova` and render with `LaTeX`.

If in my `matplotlibrc` file I specify

```
font.family : Proxima Nova
```

then the figure renders with the font `Proxima Nova`. This means that the font is installed on my system (as it is) and matplotlib can use it. However, if in the `matplotlibrc` file I also specify

```
text.usetex: True
```

then, even though I have specified `Proxima Nova` as the font, the figure renders in the default `LaTeX` font, which I guess is `Computer Modern`.

I have tried

```
matplotlib.font_manager._rebuild()
```

In the source code file and also have tried specifying the fonts in the source code file and not in the `matplotlibrc` file. However I always get the same result. I have also followed all the advice on [this help page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html), including making sure that latex, dvipng and ghostscript are all the PATH variable. However nothing seems to work.

I would like to note that I can use `Proxima Nova` separately when compiling Latex documents, so that should not be an issue either.

How can I get `matplotlib` to be able to use a non-default font and render with `LateX` at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

After some further investigation, I was able to get to use `Proxima Nova` with `Latex`, although there are still some outstanding issues.

The main issue is that if the font `Proxima Nova` is used with Latex, one needs to use `Lualatex` and not plain Latex. Here is the [Matplotlib instruction on using matplotlib with Lualatex](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/pgf.html).

The key to getting things to work was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32727230/15779032).

At the very beginning of my .py file, I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.use("pgf")

mpl.rcParams.update({
    'font.family': 'sans-serif',
    'text.usetex': True,
    'pgf.rcfonts': False,
    'pgf.texsystem': 'lualatex',
    'pgf.preamble': r'\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Proxima Nova}',
})
```

The code above should be placed at the very top of the code, **above any other imports**.

The problem, however is that this solution works only after performing the following steps:

1. Delete the .matplotlib/tex.cache folder and restart spyder
2. Replace `'font.family': 'sans-serif'` and `\setmainfont{Proxima Nova}` with `'font.family': 'serif'` and `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` respectively. Run python once.
3. Revert back to `'font.family': 'sans-serif'` and
   `\setmainfont{Proxima Nova}` and run python again.
4. The output with the correct font is produced.

Unless the above 4 steps are performed, the output is compiled with the default `DejaVu Sans` font and not with `Proxima Nova`. I am not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

After getting help on the matplotlib github forum, I was pointed to the following solution:

```
mpl.rcParams.update({
'font.family': 'sans-serif',
'text.usetex': True,
'pgf.rcfonts': False,
'pgf.texsystem': 'lualatex',
'pgf.preamble': r'\usepackage{fontspec} \setsansfont{Proxima Nova}',
})
```

In other words you need to use `setsansfont` in stead of `setmainfont`.  You can see [the matplotlib forum page here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20110).